# Collecting email for log in and authentication but not storing email in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making a social media site. I want to authenticate and verify people's accounts with their emails. I also want them to log in using their email, but I don't want to be able to see my users' email addresses because I want them to have privacy. Ideally, they should each just have a userID and their email will be associated with that userID, but I won't be able to see it.

Still, I want the ability to ban people by userID, and then for their associated email to also be banned from my social media, but I do not want to know whose email I just banned from my app. Basically, on this page, I would prefer if it did not tell me what my email was:

[image]

I'm using the very basic code to sign up users:

`Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass`

How might I modify this code?

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you explain more?

Comment: Let me know if this is clearer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want some sort of application-specific administration console for banning users without knowing their identity.

There is no way to change the display of the list of users in the Firebase Authentication console.

The most common approach is to build the needed application administration functionality yourself using the Firebase Admin SDK, and then expose that to the application administrators.

Answer (score 0):

As @Frank van Puffelen said,

You can't change the view of Firebase console. and it will show you the email,userid and some basic information always.

How do you know the UserId of people? for getting userId in some cases, you need the email id.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but I know the userID of people because I need them to register with their school email, but I don't want to violate their privacy!